# When to center/normalize data so as to increase generalization?

Tags: training-data

Given a high dimensional data set and applying PCA or some other dimension reduction technique to the data, often centering and sometimes normalization is required. When given a data set to break into training/test/validation sets, it seems like the centering and normalization should only be done on the training set and those values (mean/sd) for each variable should be saved. Then when computing validation/testing error rates the validation/testing data sets should be centered and normalized corresponding to the values computed for the training data, not their own intrinsic values of these parameters. Is this in general correct?